# How to create url with same table as shown in the pictures

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everything is working fine, but I want to make url with same table of contactUs with url. I am trying to do when the user has been request form it show everything in the table.

[image: this is the picture of table]

```js
var config = {
     apiKey: "=================",
    authDomain: "=================",
    databaseURL: "================",
    projectId: "===========",
    storageBucket: "====================",
    messagingSenderId: "====================="
};

//initialize firebase
   firebase.initializeApp(config);
   var database = firebase.database();
   var storage = firebase.storage();
   var firebaseContactsCollection = database.ref().child('ContactUs');

function submitOrder() {

    var data = {

        Name: $('#NameField').val(),
        Email: $('#EmailsField').val(),
        Subject: $('#SubjectField').val(),
        Message: $('#MessageField').val(),
     //   file: $('#fileButton').val(),
    };

    firebaseContactsCollection.push(data);


};


var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

function URL(snap) {
    var url = snap.downloadURL;

       firebase.database().ref().child('ContactUs').push(url);

}


function img() {

    var folder = this.files[0];

    var getf = storage.ref("ContactUsImagesfiles/" + new Date());
    getf.put(folder).then(URL);
}

fileButton.onchange = img;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling `push()` every time that you are saving data. The `push()` method is different from `set()` in that it is creating a unique ID and storing your data as a child below that. While `set()` will just store the data at your reference.

You can [call `push()` without storing any data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), to get a unique ID to work with. Do that first, as a global variable or something that you can pass into your functions.

```
// Get a key for a your form
var firebaseContactsCollection = database.ref().child('ContactUs');
var newFormSubmissionKey = firebaseContactsCollection.push().key;

function submitOrder() {
  // ...
  firebaseContactsCollection.child(newFormSubmissionKey).set(data);
}

function URL(snap) {
  var url = snap.downloadURL; 
  firebaseContactsCollection.child(newFormSubmissionKey).child("url").set(url);
}
```

When you store the URL in the second function, don't forget to also make a reference to the node that you want to save it to.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I was trying to do your solution. I dont what wrong with that i tried all times but i couldn't get  It also i am still new in firebase . would you please edit some code i put my code in the jsfiddle [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/v36c1qnm/1/ ) Thank you for your help

Comment: I can see that you added a number of new attempts to use different ways of storing your data also. You're doing a bit too many things at once instead of implementing according one strategy and sticking to that one. Try to not over-complicate it too much. I've made some changes to your fiddle and I hope it helps.

Comment: I check the fiddle the same my code. Have you been uploaded it Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, you are looking at your base version of the fiddle. Please look at your newer version: https://jsfiddle.net/v36c1qnm/3

Comment: This one is working for me like that but the url  image is not given it show me fakepictures please check the new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5yoL2dtf/

Comment: Your original question was regarding the wrong usage of `push()`. This is getting a bit off topic. Perhaps you want to ask a new question if you're ending up with followup issues. And you'd be very helpful in return if you would accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped with the storing data in same location as original question stated.

Comment: I got it now everything is solved it. I appreciate your help Dennis